# passing & using an implicit function without defining it

Tags: scala, implicit

I have not defined the function `ev` anywhere. Then, how come the below code works? Don't implicits have to be defined somewhere in scope for them to be used?

```
def same[T, U](x: U)(implicit ev: U => T): T = {ev(x)}
same(2) // 2
```

Comment: To extend @TravisBrown answer, You can also do: `same[Long, Int](2)` and see that it still compiles, because `Int` has an implicit called `int2long` defined on it, which would make this work. When magic like this happens, always think about which implicits are brought into scope for you, wtihout explicitly requesting them

Comment: Thanks Yuval, the confusing part was on what basis the compiler was inferring the `T` (before it searched for an implicit.) This is my first brush with the implicit $conforms method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any time you have questions like this, a good place to start is by using the Scala reflection API in the REPL to ask the compiler what's going on:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{ reify, showCode }
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{reify, showCode}

scala> def same[T, U](x: U)(implicit ev: U => T): T = ev(x)
same: [T, U](x: U)(implicit ev: U => T)T

scala> showCode(reify(same(2)).tree)
res0: String = $read.same(2)(Predef.$conforms)
```

So `ev` is provided by [`Predef.$conforms`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Predef$@$conforms[A]:<:<[A,A]), an implicit method that will give you an instance of `A <:< A` for any `A`, where [`<:<`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Predef$$$less$colon$less) extends `Function1`.

So that's one clue. Figuring out the rest requires thinking a little about type inference. When you call `same(2)`, the compiler figures out that the expression `2` has type `Int`, and infers that `U` is `Int`. Next it needs to figure out what `T` is, and to do that it goes looking for implicit functions from `Int` to `x` for some type `x`.

This is where `$conforms` comes in. It's the only such method in scope, so the compiler chooses it, which means that `ev` is of type `Int => Int` and `T` has to be `Int`, and you're done.

Comment: That's a neat reflection trick. I always use `scalac -Xprint..` to look at the tree.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yeah, `scalac -Xprint` is useful as well, but I find it noisier and less convenient for self-contained examples like this.

Comment: It definitely brings in much more noise. I'll be sure to remember this :)